# How to get the parent records if no child or grand child records are present in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a scenario in which I need to retrieve the parent record if the child records are not present by showing just the parent records and child records as NULL. The structure is represented like this.

```
SELECT A.ROW_ID AS PARENT_ROW_ID,
           B.ROW_ID AS CHILD_ROW_ID,
          C.ROW_ID AS GRANDCH_ROW_ID
  FROM MANAGER A,
       EMPLOYEE B,
       CONTRACTOR C
 WHERE A.ROW_ID(+) = B.PAR_ROW_ID
   AND B.ROW_ID = C.PAR_ROW_ID
   AND A.ROW_ID IN ('1-HC3')
```

So, when I execute this all it is returning zero records instead of giving me the parent records. Of course, on other note, there are other records which have child records and they are coming properly. Please suggest me what to do in this scenario

Comment: Why do you only have one outer-join operator? You might find it easier to figure this out if you use ANSI join syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the query to use ANSI joins makes it a lot clearer what the join conditions are:

```
SELECT A.ROW_ID AS PARENT_ROW_ID,
       B.ROW_ID AS CHILD_ROW_ID,
       C.ROW_ID AS GRANDCH_ROW_ID
FROM   MANAGER A
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       EMPLOYEE B ON ( A.ROW_ID = B.PAR_ROW_ID )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       CONTRACTOR C ON ( B.ROW_ID = C.PAR_ROW_ID )
WHERE  A.ROW_ID = '1-HC3'
```

**Edit - To answer your comment**

Just check if the type is one of the ones that you want or otherwise if it is `NULL`.

```
SELECT A.ROW_ID AS PARENT_ROW_ID,
       B.ROW_ID AS CHILD_ROW_ID,
       C.ROW_ID AS GRANDCH_ROW_ID
FROM   MANAGER A
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       EMPLOYEE B ON ( A.ROW_ID = B.PAR_ROW_ID )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       CONTRACTOR C ON ( B.ROW_ID = C.PAR_ROW_ID )
WHERE  A.ROW_ID = '1-HC3'
AND    (   B.TYPE IN ( 'SALES', 'MARKET', 'HR' )
       OR  B.TYPE IS NULL )
```

Comment: Thank you! When I see the data structure, I found that the grand child is present in the same table as child. There are many types in child table. There are values for some types. But there is no value for a type and that should also be shown NULL. I tried below, but it didn't fetch data for the type which is not present in child table.
SELECT A.ROW_ID AS PARENT_ROW_ID, B.ROW_ID AS CHILD_ROW_ID, C.ROW_ID AS GCH_ROW_ID FROM MANAGR A LEFT OUTER JOIN EMP B ON ( A.ROW_ID = B.PAR_ROW_ID ) LEFT OUTER JOIN  EMP C ON (B.ROW_ID = C.PAR_NEW_ID) WHERE B.TYPE IN ('SALES', 'MARKET','HR') A.ROW_ID = '1-HC3'